# Why does this compile? —> int foo = foo = 5;

Tags: c#

Why does this line compile?

```
int foo = foo = 5;
```

I found this in a system I'm maintaining and can't understand its purpose.

Comment: Do you have a class member called `foo`?

Comment: Can you do a binary search through the source control to find when the change was introduced? It's possibly just a typo where a person has pasted "foo = 5" on top of the previous initialised value of foo, causing the harmless repetition.

Comment: @Lee there is no class named `foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`= Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its **right-hand operand**
>   in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted **by its left-hand
>   operand** and **returns the value as its result.**

Your code works like right hand `foo = 5;` works and it returns `5` as value to `int foo` which is already `5`.

That's why

```
int foo = foo = 5;
```

is equal to

```
int foo = (foo = 5);
```

is also equal to

```
int foo = 5;
```

Comment: Why it will not throw exception that 'foo' is not declared in (foo = 5)

Comment: @andy I think you are confused because of mine. `int foo` at the beginning waits for a result the left part of the first `=` operator. It is already defined as a variable. I used `()` to pointing the _return value_ of `foo = 5` at the and. That's why I think you are confused.

Answer (score 5):

There is no purpose. It is equivalent to:

```
int foo = 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, first you declare integer value:

```
int foo
```

then you assign it

```
int foo =
```

the value to assign foo is

```
foo = 5
```

since `foo` is *declared earlier* and *returns result* (5) it is quite OK;

Finally:

1. Declared local variable `int foo`
2. Is assigned to `int foo =`
3. the expression `int foo = foo = 5;`
4. The expression set `5` to foo and return `5`

Answer (score 0):

**To compile and to have a purpose are two different things.**

it compiles because `foo = 5` returns `5`, which can be assigned to `foo`. Which doesn't have a purpose, because `foo` is already set to `5`.

Most probably the result of a refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

it says foo equals 5 and foo equals foo

resulting in foo being 5.

In this case it has no use at all.

but let's say:

```
int foo;
int bar;

foo = bar = 5;
```

will result in foo and bar both being equal to 5.

I'm not saying it is good or has a purpose, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Your code says it's setting the same variable to the same value, so there's no purpose to that, but this compile because C# allows you to set the same value to multiple variables in one line that way. An example to make it easier to understand:

```
var foo = 3;
var bar = 1;
foo = bar = 5;
Console.WriteLine("foo: {0}, bar: {1}", foo, bar); // Output: foo: 5, bar: 5
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it compile? Because nobody added a feature to the compiler that prevents this kind of weirdness; it's probably too low-priority compared to other features that could be added instead.

As to "what does it do?", like others have said, the `=` operator returns its right operand, which is useful in some situations, e.g. `while( (line = ReadLine()) != null )`. So it sets `foo` to 5, and then sets `foo` to 5... again.